# Multi-thread php parser

Tags: php

I have parser for cli with multi curl from https://github.com/chuyskywalker/rolling-curl I need change rolling curl for https://github.com/marcushat/RollingCurlX And I really break my brain already. Sorry, I haven't examples, only https://github.com/marcushat/RollingCurlX/blob/master/README.md https://github.com/marcushat/RollingCurlX/blob/master/src/rollingcurlx.class.php

Maybe im stupid or haven't knowledge for this, but i really need it work. Will glad any help. Alternative multi curl is possible, I need threads.

p.s. add sites to file without "http/s", only with [www].site.com or just site.com

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit','-1');
require __DIR__ .'/src/RollingCurl/RollingCurl.php';
require __DIR__ .'/src/RollingCurl/Request.php';
$rc = new \RollingCurl\RollingCurl();
$i=0;
$content = file('c:/1.txt');
$arr = array();
foreach ($content as $string){
    $url = trim($string);
    $plugin = explode('.',$url);
    $plugin1 = '/'.$plugin[0];
    $url1 = $url.$plugin1;
    $arr[] = $url1;
}
print "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++".PHP_EOL;
$sites = array_reverse($arr);
$options = array(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 15);
foreach ($sites as $url){
    $request = new \RollingCurl\Request($url);
    $request->setOptions($options);
    $rc->add($request);
}
$rc->setCallback(function(\RollingCurl\Request $request, \RollingCurl\RollingCurl $rc){
    $out = $request->getResponseText();
    $vuln = explode('.',$out);
    if(isset($vuln[1])){
        print PHP_EOL . $request->getUrl(). PHP_EOL;
    }else{
    }
})->execute();
```

Comment: Can you explain what isn't working? Are you getting an error/exception?

Comment: This parser works, but i do not see how i can realize it on more newer version of multi curl